# Is there a way to quickly copy the same ordering and layout from manage fields to manage displays?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type I made in Drupal that has over 50+ fields and all sorts of fieldsets, divs, and horizontal tabs.  I got the Manage Fields ordering and look to be what I want, but the manage display is all out of order and missing some field groups like the divs, fieldsets, and horizontal tabs.  I would need to add them all back in one-by-one!  Is there a quick way I can just click a button that would automatically take the existing layout from "Manage Fields" and use that for "Manage Display" for a content type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this has been posted for more than a week and nobody has responded, then I am going to assume that there is no quick and easy way.  I just ended up recreating the display by hand.  Oh well.